# How to stop intercepting Zxing intents in my app?

Tags: android, android-intent, zxing

I just emailed the dev and was asking him about this stuff.

Basically, I followed this:
http://damianflannery.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/integrate-zxing-barcode-scanner-into-your-android-app-natively-using-eclipse/

The person I'm working for isn't allowing me to use the Intent mechanism (same old reason.. can't make the users install another app), so I've to integrate the scanning functionality in my app.

I want to make sure that my app doesn't intercept intents for the QR Code scanner app. Right now, its doing that (in my Manifest..)

Do I need to rename the ZXing library project (and all of its packages)?
If I do need that, how would I do it? (Refactoring?)

Remember that I do need the QR scanning functionality from their library in my app.

Kindly help. I'm new :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You remove `<intent-filter>` declarations that you are not using. Ideally don't use anything in our namespace -- nobody really should be in a third-party app.

Comment: I'm only using ONE intent-filter.. If I remove that, my app won't do anything :s

Comment: I mean <intent-filter> that are not from your app but copied from ours.